# iPhone Development - Using Data from another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

First view:
consists of a textview(user input) & button(pressing on this button takes u to the second view)

Second View:
consists of a label

i want the label to display what the user wrote in the first view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this in .h file in SecondViewController

```
NSString *strUserInput;
```

Make below function in seconviewcontroller

```
-(void)setUserInput:(NSString *)strEntered{
    strUserInput=strEntered;
}
```

Now In first view controller do like this:

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setUserInput:txtUserInput.text];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In secondViewController viewWillAppear Method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      lblUserInput.text = strUserInput;
}
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using navigationContoller then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setUserInput:txtUserInput.text];
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```

Comment: thnx :) but pushing views is only used in navigation based apps, what if mine is a window-based one?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are creating second view when buttonClick. Just pass the data of textView (`textView.text`) to constructor of second view. Then you can set data to the label in `viewDidLoad()` method.