# iPhone App Dev - Return Values From Child To Parent View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a parent view controller which loads a child view using presentmodalview. To be precise, this child view is a login page.

The login page has two textfields (email and password) and a 'login' button. When the login button is pressed, providing the data input is valid, I would like to send the user details to the root view controller who will then create a user object if the user exists or otherwise present a uialertview indicating to the user that invalid details have been entered.

In my child view I have the following function linked to the 'login button':

```
-(IBAction) signIn:(NSString*)userEmail with:(NSString*)userPassword{
    //takes text field values and instantiates a dbConnector object to 
    //check to see if user exists - must also post uialertview if user details incorrect
    NSString* uName = [email text];
    NSString* pword = [password text];
    userDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:uName, pword, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", userDetails);
}
```

What is the best way to pass the userDetails array back to the rootviewcontroller after the button has been pressed?

SOLUTION - Protocols & Delegates

Answer (score 1):

Create UserDeatails array in the ParentViewController and Set its Value when the Button is Pressed in ChildViewController.

But you have to create object of the ParentViewController as like;

ParentViewController *parentView = [[ParentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParentViewControllerName" bundle:nil ];

parentView.userDeatails = userDetails_in_ChildView;

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your user object before pushing or present another view controller.

Refer **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537026/iphone-development-using-data-from-another-view/6537139#6537139)**. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable into Your Delegate file like

String *strUsername;
String *strPassword;

And also create property and synthesize for that..

then after create a object of your delegate where ever you want like this..

NavigationBarAppDelegate *appDelegate= (NavigationBarAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.strUsername = uName;
appDelegate.strPassword = pword;

now this value is get every war..just get it creating delegate object like above...

NavigationBar is a name of my application.